# Use of "Should" at the beginning of a sentence

Tags: sentence-construction

So, I am given this sentence:

> Father will send you a message if his flight is cancelled.

I am supposed to preserve the meaning of this sentence and transform it into another sentence beginning with "Should". So, I thought of this (I don't really know why I thought of this though):

> Should his flight **gets** cancelled, your father will send you a message.

However, some of my classmates are saying that the correct version is:

> Should his flight **get** cancelled, your father will send you a message.

I am confused. Which one is correct and why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Should can also go at the beginning of the sentence. In this case, if is dropped.

1. Should it rain, there will be no picnic today. (= If it should rain, there will be no picnic today.)
   Should she arrive, ask her to wait.
2. Should she fail the test, she will lose her job. (= If she should fail the test, she will lose her job.)

---

- "Should I..."
- "Were I to..."
- "If I..."

Or

- "Should it rain Saturday..."
- "Were it to rain Saturday..."
- "If it rains Saturday..."

These forms all convey the same meaning, but they are very different in style. The only form (of the above) that appears commonly is "If". The others sound formal / poetic / literary.

---

These examples have been taken from various sources on the net.
We can clearly see that 'she' goes with 'fail' and 'it' with 'rain'. The subject-verb stuff is not followed here. Moreever 'gets' sounds odd in this case.

So, your classmates win in this case.

Comment: The things that sound odd are most of the time incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

The form "Should his flight get (*or be*) cancelled ..." contains a *bare infinitive*.

> The infinitive without the marker **to** (bare-infinitive) is used after the auxiliaries shall, should, ...
>   [- englishgrammar.org](http://www.englishgrammar.org/bare-infinitive/)

In your example, the phrase to consider is *should get* because *get* is the verb that *should* refers to. The *bare infinitive* is used after the auxiliary *should*, so you should use *get* instead of *gets*.